# splitting values to a column with case statement in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-statement

Need help in splitting values in a column. Here's what I got so far

```
select
recordid, productname,
case when future06 like '%418%' then (Books
case when future06 like '%421%' then (Video) else null
end
from schema.dbo.table1
```

`Books` and `Video` are two main products under `future06` column.
Instead of having `future06` as the third column, I would like to have
both `Books` and `Video` alongside `recordid` and `productname`.

Would life to have the output look like:

```
RecordID   ProductName  Books   Video
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
select
    RecordID
    , ProductName
    , Books = case when future06 like '%418%' then future06 else null end
    , Video = case when future06 like '%421%' then future06 else null end
from
    schema.dbo.table1
```

Comment: that you so much, now if it only gets the number of items sold to its respective column? any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
recordid, productname,
case when future06 like '%418%' then future06 else null end as Books,
case when future06 like '%421%' then future06 else null end as Video
from schema.dbo.table1


select
recordid, productname,
COUNT(case when future06 like '%418%' then 1 else 0 end) as NoOfBooks,
COUNT(case when future06 like '%421%' then 1 else 0 end) as NoOfVideo
from schema.dbo.table1 
group by recordid, productname

select
recordid, productname,
COUNT(case when future06 like '%418%' then 1 else 0 end) as NoOfBooks,
COUNT(case when future06 like '%421%' then 1 else 0 end) as NoOfVideo, 
COUNT(*) as Total 
from schema.dbo.table1 
group by recordid, productname
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, now how would or where would I include a count function and add additional column called total adding both books and videos?

Comment: getting an error:<br>aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: missing group by clause w/ fields recordId, productName

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I guess my next question will be, if I included another column called Total, how would I add Books and Video together? Thank you!